# Document Version Update in Document Libarary

Tags: document-library, document, version-history

My site having 3 users, but version update when ever user1(Edit Document) Check out and check in update version remaining users(user2,user3  --  view) check out and check in view document how restrict version update for these 2 users.

Comment: Do you mean: User1 checks out the doc, edits it, checks it in, and the version number increments. User2 and User3 goes to view the document, but they check it out instead, and when they check it back in it increments the version.

Comment: User1 Check in Increment Version this is ok, but User2 and User3 Check in Restrict to Increment Version(doesn't change version)